# Accessing parent window elements from iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

- I have a `customer.jsp` page with an `iframe`.
- `iframe` has a button. on click of the button, i need to access a dialog box which is inside `customer.jsp` page.
- I tried `window.parent.document.getElementById('formDialog');` but am getting `null` value.

Comment: you have 500 correct answers, pick one

Answer (score 9):

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('target');
```

both resources should be on same origin

Answer (score 4):

Communication between an iframe and parent document is not possible for cross-origin resources. It will only work if the iframe and the containing page are from the same host, port and protocol - e.g. http://example.com:80/1.html and http://example.com:80/2.html

```
 Assuming both resources are from the same origin
```

In the iframe, window.parent refers to the global object of the parent document, not the document object itself. I believe you would need to use `parent.document.getElementById('formDialog')`

Answer (score 1):

You can access parent window elements through `parent.document.getElementById('formDialog');`

If you get null are you able to get that element within the context of that Iframes parent? Are you referencing the right ID and the right parent?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope this helps. Let's say I have CallParentFunction from button click of a button in an iframe.

```
function CallParentFunction(){
     if (top && top.opener && top.opener.top) {
        top.opener.document.getElementById('formDialog'); 
     }
      else {
        top.document.getElementById('formDialog'); 

     }
}
```